# Windows Docker Golang: exec /app/server: exec format error

Tags: docker, go

I developed an golang application and now I'm trying to run it on Docker. But when I run the image, the container keep showing this error message: `exec /app/server: exec format error`

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 golang:1.21-bookworm as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./src/. ./
RUN go mod download

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -v -o server ./cmd/main.go

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 debian:bookworm-slim
RUN set -x && apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=builder /app/server /app/server

RUN chmod +x /app/server

CMD ["/app/server"]
```

My host OS is Windows 11, and I'm trying to run the image on Debian Slim with amd64 platform.

I tried to add `--platform=linux/amd64` in different places (including the Dockerfile and the docker build command) to make sure that the platform is not the issue.

Comment: I've tested your `Dockerfile` (using a [basic "hello world"](https://gobyexample.com/hello-world) app) on a Windows 11 machine and it ran fine. Can you please test a similar app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I omitted a compile error. I recommend you to build/run the app locally before building with docker. Use `go build` or `go run` commands.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).